# Condition on Hermitian matrices

Tags: matrices, random-matrices

I have been working through Roger A. Horn and Charles R. Johnson's Matrix Analysis book and have come stuck on one direction of an if and only if proof. It goes as follows;

Suppose $A, B \in \mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$ are Hermitian. Show that,

$x^*Ax = x^*Bx \implies A = B$

My thought process is as follows,

$x^*Ax = x^*Bx$

$\implies x^*(A-B)x = 0$

as this must hold for all $x$ then

$A=B$

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: $x^*$ is the complex conjugate transpose of $x$, I might add.

Answer (score 1):

You may make use of the [polarization identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarization_identity)

\begin{aligned}
\Re(y^\ast Mx)&=\frac14\left[(x+y)^\ast M(x+y) - (x-y)^\ast M(x-y)\right],\\
\Im(y^\ast Mx)&=\frac14\left[(x-iy)^\ast M(x-iy) - (x+iy)^\ast M(x+iy)\right].
\end{aligned}

Comment: How would I use these to prove $x^*Ax = x^*Bx$? Also, I have never seen these used in my delivered lectures, so I assume that there is a way that doesn't involve these. However,  I am still interested.

Comment: @MrVanilla You don't use them to prove that $x^\ast Ax=x^\ast Bx$. Instead, if $x^\ast Ax=x^\ast Bx$ for every vector $x$, you use the polarisation identities to prove that $y^\ast Ax=y^\ast Bx$ for every pair of vectors $x$ and $y$.